# How do I make a 3D bar plot or chart

Tags: plotting

I want to implement this drawing in Mathematica:

[image]

What function can I use to implement this? I tried `DiscretePlot3D` but that doesn't work.

```
DiscretePlot3D[{ {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 
1 }, {0.3778205803916443`, 0.34988310218156105`, 
0.34022823666742175`, 0.3414700269550834`, 0.32781003385300567`, 
0.3202583095504828`, 0.3197914113797346`, 0.3077319222194619`, 
0.30450999238267246`}, {45, 45, 45, 50, 50, 50, 55, 55, 55}}, {t, 
0, 1}, ExtentSize -> Full]ode here
```

Comment: [BarChart3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart3D.html) is fits what you want to do, I think. It's also quite easy to draw that plot using `Graphics3D`.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Start small.  Often you will find the best way to solve a problem is by not solving it;  put it on the back burner.   Fire up Mathematica and type in BarChart3D, put the cursor on it, a drop down menu appears, click the "i" for info.  Now study it and work through all the examples, now just plot one of the blocks in your diagram then 2 or three, then work to do them all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must rearrange your data a bit. The first and last row show 3 time the same coordinates. Therefore I rearranged the third row according to the picture you included. Further, it is custom to have the z-value at the end, not in the middle. So I put the your third row at place 2. Then, for easier processing, I transposed your data to get triples of coordinates. Here is the code:

```
dat = {{0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 
    1}, {0.3778205803916443`, 0.34988310218156105`, 
    0.34022823666742175`, 0.3414700269550834`, 0.32781003385300567`, 
    0.3202583095504828`, 0.3197914113797346`, 0.3077319222194619`, 
    0.30450999238267246`}, {45, 50, 55, 45, 50, 55, 45, 50, 55}};
dat = Transpose@dat[[{1, 3, 2}]];
{d1, d2, tmp} = (Max @@ # - Min @@ #)/10 & /@ Transpose[dat]
Graphics3D[{
  t = Cuboid[# {1, 1, 0} - {d1, d2, 0}, # + {d1, d2, 0}] & /@ dat
  }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Here is an implementation that uses `BarChart3D` and gives a result which looks much more like the image in your question. It uses tooltips to show the viewer the full parameter set for each bar.

```
ttStyle = {CellFrame -> 2, CellFrameColor -> Black};

Module[{given, ttkeys, ttvals, tooltips, data}, 
  given = 
    {{0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1}, 
     {0.377821, 0.349883, 0.340228, 0.34147, 0.32781, 0.320258, 0.319791, 0.307732, 0.30451}, 
     {45, 45, 45, 50, 50, 50, 55, 55, 55}};
  ttkeys = given[[2]];
  ttvals =
    MapThread[
      Row[{#1[[1]], ", k = ", #1[[2]], ", ", #2}] &, 
      {Tuples[{Union[given[[1]]], Union[given[[3]]]}], given[[2]]}];
  tooltips = AssociationThread[ttkeys, ttvals];
  data = Transpose[Partition[given[[2]], 3]];
  BarChart3D[
    Map[Tooltip[#, tooltips[#], TooltipStyle -> ttStyle] &, data, {-1}],
    ChartLayout -> "Grid",
    ChartStyle -> RGBColor[0.40, 0.60, 0.],
    BarSpacing -> {Large, Large},
    PlotLabel -> Style["Implizite Volatilitaten\n", 14],
    FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]]
```

[image: chart]